# How to Remove Double Lines Detected Along the Edges by Edge Detector?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, edge-detection, canny-edge-detector

I'm trying to take real time input for hand gestures with web cam, then processing the images to feed them to a neural network. I wrote this processing function to make the hand features look prominent:

```
def image_processing(image, count):
    roi = image[42:338, 2:298] 
    cv2.imwrite('a/'+str(count)+'.png', roi)
               
    img = cv2.imread('a/'+str(count)+'.png')
   
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),2)

    th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,10,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
    ret, res = cv2.threshold(th3, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
    res = cv2.Canny(res,100,200) 
    cv2.imshow("Canny", res)
    cv2.imwrite('a/'+str(count)+'.png', res)
```

**--Edit--**

The input and the output images are as follows :

[image] [image]

It's obvious that double lines, instead of one, are detected along the edges. I want to make them single. If I apply just Canny edge detection algo, then the edges are not very prominent.

Comment: Have you considered using a [max filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/sliding-window-minimum-and-maximum-filter-in-matlab)?

Comment: Could you share the input image?

Comment: @Royi : Shared. Plz check the edit section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following code:

```
clear();
close('all');
mI = im2double(imread('bCfdb.png')); %<! Loading the image
vBlurStd = [0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2];

mII = sum(cat(3, 0.299, 0.587, 0.114) .* mI, 3); %<! Y (Luminosity like channel)

hFigure = figure('Position', [100, 100, 1200, 900]);
hTiledChartLayout = tiledlayout(3, 3);

kk = 0;
for ii = 1:3
    for jj = 1:3
        kk = kk + 1;
        if(kk == 1)
            mE = edge(mII, 'canny');
        else
            mE = edge(imgaussfilt(mII, vBlurStd(kk)), 'canny');
        end
        nexttile();
        imshow(mE);
    end
end

set(hTiledChartLayout, 'TileSpacing', 'tight', 'Padding', 'tight');
```

This is the result:

[image]

#### What Does the Script?

1. We set an array of different blur radius to evaluate the algorithm at - `vBlurStd`.
2. We load the image and convert it into `Double` in the range `[0, 1]` - `mI = im2double(imread('bCfdb.png'));`
3. We extract the `Y` channel from the [`YCbCr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color model - `mII = sum(cat(3, 0.299, 0.587, 0.114) .* mI, 3);`.
4. The algorithm is basically blurring the image with Gaussian Blur and then applying [Canny Edge Detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) - `edge(imgaussfilt(mII, vBlurStd(kk)), 'canny');`.

The images are left to right, top down by their blur radius.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python. Did you write just the algo or is it in  language other than Python?

Comment: It's MATLAB. But you can get very similar results with Python. Just extract the Y channel, Do a small blur and then Canny Edge Detection.

Comment: Could you plz convert it into Python? I'm absolutely unaware of Matlab syntax which is why I don't understand how the code works.

Comment: @Debbie, I described the algorithm. All the ingredients are already in your code.

Comment: Thanks..I'll check.